# Svg on hover makes a group visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to make a particular group visible on hovering on other group.I have made unique id's for groups which i want to style.
After that i need to animate them also in the process of showing the group.
So i tried display:none as a last resort but didn't work, i want to use opacity:0 - 1; or visibility will be best thing to happen.

Second issue is i don't want to use inline svg , so i shifted from 'img' tag to object tag, but then i didn't found any useful resources to implement that. I am taking the svg code from other service provider instead of storing it in local storage.
Is it possible that only one svg file, or any other file that i can link with my html file so that i wont be needing to add any css or js in my parent css,js files.

So in this sample,

```
g#a:hover + #content-a{
display: block !important;
} 
#a:hover + #content-a{
display: block !important;
}
```

Initially

```
#content-a{ display:none}
#content-b{ display:none}
```

Also some article i read talk about using

```
<use />
```

Will it be more efficient. Also how i will me able to make it inline on loading up through vanilla javascript.

Here is the link - [Sample](https://codepen.io/cogenex/pen/oEMmzq)

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 0):

**E + F**: an F element *immediately* preceded by an E element

**E ~ F**: an F element preceded by an E element

While `display: block` works, the default actually is `display: inline`

```css
#a:hover ~ #content-a {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: browser is unable to catch groupElement:hover, but actual css can changed using svg:hover, why is it so?

Comment: Read up on [hit-testing](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/interact.html#pointer-processing) and [event flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow).